# Accessing global variable and asynchronous issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables, asynchronous, global-variables

Below is some code I've just started to work on (an avatar generator experiment). I want to be able to click on a button and change the position of the canvas element, but I'm having troubles with some things.

In the click event function on the button I console.log out canvasTop ...

```
console.log(this.canvasTop);
```

... however, it gets undefined. I can access the variable anywhere else in the code except inside this click event function. Why is it like this?

The other thing is the next two lines ...

```
this.canvasTop += 10;
AvatarGenerator.canvas();
```

... on the first on these lines I want to iterate the canvasTop value, and on the second line call the function that draws the canvas. However, it seems like the second line runs before the first line (yes, JS is asynchronous I know) which means that the canvas element won't move until the next time I click the button. How can I solve this?

Thanks in advance!

**The code:**

```
AvatarGenerator = {

    canvasTop: 50,
    canvasLeft: 50, 
    canvas: $('#canvas')[0],
    context: canvas.getContext('2d'),

    init: function() {
        AvatarGenerator.canvas();
        AvatarGenerator.toolBox();
    },

    canvas: function() {
        console.log(this.canvasTop); // <-- 50
        this.context.beginPath();
        this.context.moveTo(this.canvasLeft, this.canvasTop);
        this.context.lineTo(300, 300);
        this.context.stroke();
    },

    toolBox: function() {
        var moveLeftBtn = $('#moveLeftBtn');

        moveLeftBtn.on('click', function(){
            console.log(this.canvasTop); // <-- undefined, why?

            this.canvasTop += 10;
            AvatarGenerator.canvas();
        });
    }
};
```

Comment: `this` isn't what you think it is. `console.log(this)` solution should be relatively obvious after that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The click handler is called in a different context, so `this` doesn't point to your object anymore.

Try this:

```
var self = this;
moveLeftBtn.on('click', function(){
  console.log(self.canvasTop);

  self.canvasTop += 10;
  AvatarGenerator.canvas();
});
```

Or, for modern browsers, you can bind your object to your function so you don't need `self`:

```
moveLeftBtn.on('click', function(){
  console.log(this.canvasTop);

  this.canvasTop += 10;
  AvatarGenerator.canvas();
}.bind(this));
//^^^^^^^^^^ this determines what 'this' in the callback function is pointing to
```

Comment: In this case, you could also just use `AvatarGenerator` rather than `this` or `self`, but yes.

Comment: +1 I'd recommend looking at a jQuery plugin template to see the traditional use of `base`, but `self` in this example is the same thing and will work :)